# Why blurry the SVG elements in Chrome using Panzoom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I am using timmywil's panzoom (https://github.com/timmywil/jquery.panzoom) on SVG elements, like Google Geochart and about a month ago I have noticed when I zoom in; the SVG will be blurry. For example, see the demos:https://timmywil.github.io/jquery.panzoom/demo/
In Firefox, IE, Maxthon works very well. I am using the newest version of browsers.

Anybody knows what's wrong or how to solve this?

**SOLVED!:** I put "-webkit-backface-visibility: initial !important;" on the SVG elements style.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Chrome is automatically rasterizng the SVG.

Chrome does have lots of 'hidden' features to speed up rendering time etc of which many you can tweak for example the below.

Type [chrome://flags](http://chrome://flags) in the address bar and press enter.

Enable GPU rasterization
GPU rasterization MSAA sample count
Number of raster threads
LCD text antialiasing - Enabled

You can also quickly check varous flags [here](http://chrome://gpu)

I've found [this](https://forums.disruptorbeam.com/gota/viewthread/45756) page particular useful:

Comment: Sadly, it is not works for me, but if it would works how should I avoid that Chrome automatically rasterize the SVG by jQuery or somehow? Can you give me another advice?

Comment: I solved this by using "-webkit-backface-visibility: initial !important;" on the SVG elements.

Comment: that's great, thought I'm at a loss to see why that would prevent/force Chrome to respect the SVG vectors. Good find I'll check it out and thanks for sharing